# How to create a temporary filesystem overlay so all modified files go in one archive?

Tags: docker, overlayfs

TLDR : I would like to execute a command that may read, create or modify files in the current folder. But I'd like all modified/created file to end up in an archive, and not actually modify the current files in the folder.

Context:
I have students submitting a code that produces some files. They submit an archive with both, because some things do not work as expected on our side, so we ask students to submit the results of their code along with the code.

I deflated all students' archives. I would like to execute the code of all students. But when I try to execute the code of students and it fails, it actually overwrites files so I don't have the original from the student. I would like to keep the files submitted by the students, and get an archive that contains files created (or modified but it's not strictly necessary) during the execution.

Possible leads:

- Launch a docker with copied file. Docker does use overlay but I'm not sure how I could recover only the content of the overlay.
- Overlayfs ? However I'd like something easy and "temporary" just for the time I launch the code.
- What I want to avoid : duplicate the whole folder and launch the code in the copy.

Comment: ... or make local git repos, commit the initial contents and then run the code?

Comment: That's a good plan B. The  "overlay" solution is a bit more neat. A git folder might already exist for instance, or students could mess it up.  But it definitely works, I'm also interested in knowing the overlay solution I guess.

Comment: You can ignore existing `.git` directories and set your own (`GIT_DIR=/some/where/else`, or `git --git-dir /some/where/else`).

Comment: Have you looked into using a sbap shot file system? Snapper (http://snapper.io/overview.html) might be a solution.

Comment: @Dobbo looks good, if you can provide a small answer, I'll be happy to try and validate it if it's suitable.

Comment: @muru Thanks, didn't know! I'd still like an overlay-based solution for the sake of it.

Comment: @MappaM I've never used it myself, I just thought it might be a solution.